# How to use cast to varchar(max) with STRING_AGG using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core, sql-to-linq-conversion

I am trying to get the following part of the query to work using Entity Framework Core and Linq in C#

```
STRING_AGG(cast(EntityName as varchar(max)), ' , ') AS AllEntityNames
```

I need to concat all the `EntityName`. However, I get an error:

> STRING_AGG aggregation result exceeded the limit of 8000 bytes. Use LOB types to avoid result truncation.

when I am using

```
.Select(g => new
             {
                 AllEntityNames = string.Join(",", g.Select(p => p.EntityName )) 
             })
```

How can we do the cast to `varchar` part of the SQL query in my C# code?

Comment: It works with the CAST to VARCHAR(MAX), but fails without the cast. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vGgsSAgm). So the trick is finding the LINQ equivalent (likelly a RDMS-specific extension) that forces a CAST or CONVERT.

Comment: I'm looking at the [SqlFunctions class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions), but haven't spotted anything there yet. You might need to register a custom function. (Still looking.)

Comment: The best I can come up with is: (1) Define a custom user function in SQL server like `CREATE FUNCTION CastToVarcharMax(@value VARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS BEGIN RETURN @value END`. (2) Register the function as described in *[User-defined function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping)*. This would allow you would code something like `string.Join(",", g.Select(p => p.EntityName.CastToVarcharMax() ))`. There may be a way to map a function name directly to the SQL syntax `CAST(value AS VARCHAR(MAX)`, but I don't know how at this point.

Comment: You could also do the same for `CastToNvarcharMax()` if appropriate to your usage. You might find more somewhere in the [google "Entity Framework Core sql server custom function mapping"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Entity+Framework+Core+sql+server+custom+function+mapping) results or similar

Comment: If that's the only field you're getting, build the string **after** retrieving the data.

Comment: This is not really a proper use of ORMs in my opinion. Might as well start typing that raw sql

Comment: @siggemannen - I grant that it is somewhat of a hack. It would have been better if the built-in ORM translation of `String.Join()` would have automatically applied a conversion to force the use of the VARCHAR(MAX) variant/overload of `STRING_AGG()` to match the C#/,Net semantics, but it did not. Perhaps a bug report on EF Core is in order.

Comment: @TN i'm more thinking that one should work with a List of Entities rather than materialize some CSV strings. But yeah, agree that this seems like a bug in EF, or at least an oversight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*A bit of background: If the aggregating input to `STRING_AGG()` is a `VARCHAR(N)` or `NVARCHAR(N)` type, the result type is limited to `VARCHAR(8000)` or `NVARCHAR(4000)`, respectively. If the result would be longer, the posted error occurs.*

*To allow longer results, the input string must be converted to a `xVARCHAR(MAX)` type (referred to as "LOB types" in the error message). The question is: How do we do that from LINQ to SQL and EF Core.*

According to the [Function Mappings of the Microsoft SQL Server Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions) article, the function call `Convert.ToString(value)` will map to `CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @value)`.

This is likely intended for conversions from types other-than-string, but will also work with a string type.

Your code would then be something like:

```
.Select(g => new {
    // The Convert.ToString() below will cast EntityName to NVARCHAR(MAX).
    // This will avoid the 8000 char limit for STRING_AGG() on VARCHAR(N).
    // This comment is here for a reason. Leave it and the ToString() call.
    AllEntityNames = string.Join(
        ",",
        g.Select(p => Convert.ToString(p.EntityName))
    ) 
})
```

Comment: I've tried this in Linqpad in a similar case with EFC7 and it works perfectly.

Comment: But... if this is the _only_ column being returned (and it seems to be) its probably better to join the results in the client.

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot!